# ListRows.Add function deletes data from Original Table

Tags: excel, vba

Yesterday, my question for this issue was resolved:

[VBA Copy/Paste Data from Source Table into Target Table when DataBodyRange is Nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177811/vba-copy-paste-data-from-source-table-into-target-table-when-databodyrange-is-no)

I can now 'add' data to a table when `DataBodyRange` is `Nothing`.

However there was an unintended consequence that I can not figure out with the `ListRows.Add` approach.

Steps:

1. I call the referenced routine and select a value from the SOURCE (left side) table.  Data gets filtered and pasted correctly into the TARGET (right side) table.
2. I call the routine again.  One line from the SOURCE table is deleted immediately after the ListRows.Add function (I placed 'Stops' in the code to diagnose location of issue.)

Here is a picture of second run at first Stop.
[image: At the first STOP]

Here is a picture of the second run after the `ListRows.Add`
[image: At the second STOP - after ListRows.Add]

And here is the code with the Stops shown.

```
Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter()

Dim loSource As Excel.ListObject
Dim loTarget As Excel.ListObject
Dim SourceDataRowsCount As Long
Dim TargetDataRowsCount As Long
Dim myfilter As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim EndRow As ListRow

Set loSource = Sheets("ProductData").ListObjects("tblProductData")
Set loTarget = Sheets("ProductData").ListObjects("tblMyProducts")
Set myfilter = Range("ShipToNumber")

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, etc.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

'Delete all table rows except first row
    If Not loTarget.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
           loTarget.DataBodyRange.Delete
           loTarget.Resize Range("$J$1:$Q$2")
    End If

'Create the Filter for the Source Table & Count Number of Cells
    loSource.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=myfilter
    SourceDataRowsCount = loSource.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count

'Setup the Target Table
    If SourceDataRowsCount <> 0 Then
        Set rng = Range("tblMyProducts[#All]").Resize(SourceDataRowsCount + 1, 8)
        loTarget.Resize rng

'Check to see if there is data in table
    If Not loTarget.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        loSource.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 'Copy Data from Source Table to Target Table
        loTarget.DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Else

        STOP 'First Stop
             loTarget.ListRows.Add
        STOP 'Second Stop

        loSource.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy loTarget.DataBodyRange(1, 1)
    End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, etc.
        Sheets("ProductData").ListObjects("tblProductData").ShowAutoFilter = False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry, this Ship To location has not ordered any products in the last six months.  Please contact customer service so that your tables can be updated."
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The bottom line is I am trying to copy / paste a range of filtered values from a source table to a target table so that I can use the target table data in drop down menus, combo boxes, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Michael

Comment: What can you explain what the current problem is? I've read this a few times and I'm not picking up on what the problem is.

Comment: Just checking - are the ship to numbers supposed to be different between the first and second runs?

Comment: @ Marcucciboy2  - if you look at picture one there are two rows associated with ...984 order number in the first table - both paste are pasted in second table which is ok

Comment: @ Marcucciboy2  - if you look at picture one there are two rows associated with ...984 ship to number in the first table - both are pasted in the second table which is ok.  When I process the routine a second time with a different ship to number, it is pasted correctly.  But look at the first table, one of the two lines (...984) of the ship to number in the first table disappears!

Comment: @BigBen - that is the exact problem. One of the rows of the Ship To data for ...984 was deleted. It was the first row the source table.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately separated the two tables to two different sheets.  The problem was solved.

For whatever reason the one table kept deleting rows from the other table when it was on the same sheet.